# Best practices for using a different ConnectionString in unit test / dev and live in desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am developing a C# desktop application and have created a few unit tests for it.

I am using a Connection String that is set in a static variable inside a Settings.cs:

```
    class Settings
    {
        public static readonly string UserID = "myName";
        public static readonly string Password = "pass1";
        public static readonly string Server = "server1";
        public static readonly string Database = "db1";
        public static readonly string Timeout = "30";

        //public static readonly string ConnectionString = "User ID=" + Settings.UserID + 
        //                                                 ";Password=" + Settings.Password + 
        //                                                 ";Server=" + Settings.Server + 
        //                                                 ";Database=" + Settings.Database + 
        //                                                 ";Connection Timeout=" + Settings.Timeout;

        public static readonly string ConnectionString = "context connection=true";
    }
```

You can see what I am doing here - I have one string that I use for dev (commented out) and another that I use when deploying to the live system.

It's very irritating having to comment and uncomment these out. In ASP.NET I can use a config file and transform the connection string depending on debug/deploy, but in a desktop app I don't think there is such capability.

Is there a better way to what I am already doing?

Comment: Windows Forms, WPF, Console Applications, Web Apps & even Libraries can have a config file. Add it via "Add -> New item -> Application Configuration". Note that the executing application config is used, and never a Library config, unless that Library is a unit testing library or the primary execution/entry point

Comment: You should really look into using a config file. this is the reason they exist

Comment: Use a config file and you can also use web.config transforms with a little work. http://gunnarpeipman.com/2013/11/using-web-config-transforms-with-app-config-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically handled best by checking a setting in a file, as you said.  The details of how to do that in various application types is [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx) You can roll your own config file as an alternative, and use a `StreamReader` to read it. An example of that sort of thing is Bethesda's config files for its two major franchises, TES and Fallout.  XML is the way most do it, though for simple settings you can use a text file.   Doing it this way, you can toggle debug mode without having to recompile.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For anyone reading this in future this is the route I would go down. The only reason I don't want to use a config file is that this application is called very infrequently (every few days) and it needs very good performance. Reading a config file from disk is expensive - and yes I know the config files are cached, but the impact upon first run is still there.

I will just have to stick to my current method but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
#if DEBUG
//code when in debug mode
#else
//code when not in debug (Release, for instance)
#endif
```

Comment: Maybe it's the type of project I am creating but this didn't work for me. Everything inside the #else - #endif just appeared as commented out code.

Comment: @MSOACC Make sure you put `DEBUG` all caps. If your projet is set to debug, only the code between `#if` and `#else` will be compiled, and the rest is comment out. When you change to Release in VS, the code between `#if` and `#else` become a comment and the code between `#else` and `#endif` is compiled

Comment: That may have been my error, I am not sure. All I noticed was that after publishing via the VS2015 "Publish" method I got the code that was inside the DEBUG if/else statement. I will have another go.

Comment: You can also try the route of `if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) ` if you're working with Debug vs live.  It doesn't have the benefit of being a preprocessor instruction, but it works with the normal flow of your program and you don't have to worry so much about needed code not being compiled at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are configuration files, app.config, for desktop applications as well. You can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) article on how to read the AppSettings from your configuration. You may have to add reference to 'System.Configuration' assembly.

Its also a good practice to encrypt sensitive information like passwords in connection string. Here is an [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) document on that.